# Remove empty properties / falsy values from Object with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an object with several properties. I would like to remove any properties that have falsy values.

This can be achieved with [`compact`](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) on arrays, but what about objects?

Comment: To avoid copy-pasting this across repositories, you can use [Bit](https://github.com/teambit/bit) to [import this component](https://bitsrc.io/bit/utils/object/clean) (which has 3 tests passing & MIT license). You can also try [this NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-clear) (which might be an overkill for a small component).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could make your own underscore plugin (mixin) :

```
_.mixin({
  compactObject: function(o) {
    _.each(o, function(v, k) {
      if(!v) {
        delete o[k];
      }
    });
    return o;
  }
});
```

And then use it as a native underscore method :

```
var o = _.compactObject({
  foo: 'bar',
  a: 0,
  b: false,
  c: '',
  d: null,
  e: undefined
});
```

### Update

As [@AndreiNeculau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465684/andrei-neculau) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058193/remove-empty-properties-falsy-values-from-object-with-underscore-js/19750822#comment-33713647), this mixin affects the original object, while the original `compact` underscore method [returns a copy of the array](http://underscorejs.org/#compact).
To solve this issue and make our `compactObject` behave more like it's *cousin*, here's a minor update:

```
_.mixin({
  compactObject : function(o) {
     var clone = _.clone(o);
     _.each(clone, function(v, k) {
       if(!v) {
         delete clone[k];
       }
     });
     return clone;
  }
});
```

Comment: Since the question has an underscore reference, it would be good to mention that this does not behave like `_.compact`. It will delete properties, rather than create a shallow clone with truthy values only. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19750822/465684 below

Comment: @AndreiNeculau You're right! I seem to have missed that earlier. See my updated answer.

Comment: Why first copy all the properties of an object, then loop through them and delete falsy ones? That's unperformant. Moreover, using `delete` is generally discouraged as it immediately exposes properties with the same name from the prototype chain and also hurts performance due to "hidden classes" (V8) - changing the object structure causes the engine to do extra work. The best and shortest solution would be `_.pick(o, _.identity)`.

Answer (score 174):

Since Underscore version 1.7.0, you can use [`_.pick`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick):

```
_.pick(sourceObj, _.identity)
```

### Explanation

The second parameter to `_.pick` can be a predicate function for selecting values. Values for which the predicate returns *truthy* are picked, and values for which the predicate returns *falsy* are ignored.

> **pick** _.pick(object, *keys)
>
> Return a copy of the **object**, filtered to only have values for the allowed **keys** (or array of valid keys). Alternatively accepts a predicate indicating which keys to pick.

`_.identity` is a helper function that returns its first argument, which means it also works as a predicate function that selects truthy values and rejects falsy ones. The Underscore library also comes with a bunch of other predicates, for instance `_.pick(sourceObj, _.isBoolean)` would retain only boolean properties.

If you use this technique a lot, you might want to make it a bit more expressive:

```
var pickNonfalsy = _.partial(_.pick, _, _.identity); // Place this in a library module or something
pickNonfalsy(sourceObj);
```

Underscore version 1.6.0 provided `_.pick` as well, but it didn't accept a predicate function instead of a list of keys.

Comment: Special thanks for mentioning `_.identity` function, very handy.

Comment: This has been extremely handy! It's also possible to use `_.omit(sourceObj, _.isUndefined)` to remove only undefined values (allowing false, null, 0).

Comment: Its also possible to do `pick(obj, Boolean)` to eliminate falsey values that same approach can be used when `arr.filter(Boolean)` to clean an array from falsey values...

Comment: In ES6, this turns into ```_.pick(sourceObj, prop => prop)```

Comment: In lodash 4.4.0 `_.pick` works with property names, for this functionality as mentioned in post use `_.pickBy`

Comment: 0 is not a falsy value. this removes zero as well

Comment: No, 0 _is_ a falsy value. `0 ? 'true' : 'false'` evaluates to `'false'`.

Comment: To leave out only `null` or `undefined`-valued properties with lodash: `_.omitBy(sourceObj, _.isNil)`

Answer (score 46):

## Quick 'n Clear: `_.omitBy( source, i => !i );`

This is stated in an inverse fashion to Emil's answer.  This way imho reads clearer; it's more self explanatory.

Slightly less clean if you don't have the luxury of ES6: `_.omitBy( source, function(i){return !i;});`

### Alternate: `_.omitBy( source, _.isEmpty)`

Using **`_.isEmpty`**, instead of `_.identity` for truthiness, **will also conveniently remove empty arrays and objects from the collection and perhaps inconveniently remove numbers and dates**.  Thus the outcome is NOT an exact answer to the OP's question, however it could be useful when looking to remove empty collections.

Comment: In Lodash 4.0, this functionality is now under `omitBy`. https://lodash.com/docs#omitBy

Comment: I believe this is the same as:

```_.pick(source, i => i);```

which avoids the negation

Comment: @JeffLowery This is even better, in Lodash, because the default predicate is the identity function! `_.pickBy(source)` is all that's needed.

Comment: Note: Numbers are considered empty. `_.isEmpty(5) === true`. Thus values that are numbers will be dropped.

Answer (score 21):

With lodash's [transform](http://lodash.com/docs#transform),

```
_.transform(obj, function(res, v, k) {
  if (v) res[k] = v;
});
```

Comment: whit lodash's _.pick(obj, _.identity); shorter ^_^

Comment: This answer or @evilive's comment under it IS the answer.

Comment: a shorter variation, based on the above comment, would be `var compactObject = _.partialRight(_.pick, _.identity);`

Comment: @zaboco [In lodash v4 it should be `_.pickBy` instead of `_.pick`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503069/what-has-changed-in-lodash-from-3-to-4-that-this-code-is-not-working/39503305#39503305))

Comment: yse, `_.pickBy(object)` is all you need

Answer (score 19):

```
Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
    if (!o[k]) {
        delete o[k];
    }
});
```

Comment: And one can use underscore for `.keys` and `.forEach`.

Comment: How would this look in Underscore, then? Trying to piece it together…

Comment: +1 this is awesome man. please give me the link of `forEach` method of JS

Comment: @diEcho https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 9):

You can create a shallow clone:

```
_(obj).reduce(function(a,v,k){ 
     if(v){ a[k]=v; } 
     return a; 
},{});
```

Answer (score 5):

for object use delete.

```
for(var k in obj){

  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && !obj[k]){
    delete obj[k];
  }
}
```

Comment: since he wants an underscore solution, you could iterate over the array using one of underscore's methods

Answer (score 5):

Suddenly I needed create a function to remove recursively falsies. I hope this helps. I'm using Lodash.

```
var removeFalsies = function (obj) {
    return _.transform(obj, function (o, v, k) {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
            o[k] = _.removeFalsies(v);
        } else if (v) {
            o[k] = v;
        }
    });
};

_.mixin({ 'removeFalsies': removeFalsies });
```

Then you can use it:

```
var o = _.removeFalsies({
  foo: 'bar',
  a: 0,
  b: false,
  c: '',
  d: null,
  e: undefined,
  obj: {
    foo: 'bar',
    a: 0,
    b: false,
    c: '',
    d: null,
    e: undefined
  }
});

// {
//   foo: 'bar',
//   obj: {
//     foo: 'bar'
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 2):

I do understand the question is asking specifically how to do this with underscore, but since I came here from google, I wanted to add how to do this using ES6, plus, I really like this method

```js
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k,v],i)=>v))
```

The reason is because it creates a new Object (I want it to create a new object without modifying the previous one), uses no libraries, defines no variables, and it doesn't pollute the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

To add to gion_13's answer:

```
_.mixin({
  compactObject : function(o) {
     var newObject = {};
     _.each(o, function(v, k) {
       if(v !== null && v !== undefined) {
         newObject[k] = v
       }
     });
     return newObject;
  }
});
```

This one creates a new object and adds keys and values instead of cloning everything and deleting key-value pairs. Minor difference.

But more importantly, checks explicitly for null and undefined instead of falsey, which will delete key-value pairs that have false as a value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pickBy` from lodash.

The default signature of pickBy is `_.(sourceObj, [_.identity])` so it will remove empty properties

```js
_.pickBy(sourceObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the lodash you do like this:

```
_.pickBy(object, _.identity);
```

Answer (score -1):

Although `_.compact` is documented for use in arrays. It seems to work for objects too. I just ran the following in chrome, opera and firefox consoles:

```
var obj = {first: 1, second: null, third: 3, fourth: function(){return 5}}
undefined
_.compact(obj)

[1, 3, function()]
```

UPDATE: As the sample indicates calling `_.compact` on an object will drop the keys and return a compacted array.

Comment: But it still returns an array. The keys are lost.

Comment: You're right. Do I delete my answer then? Or does stackoverflow prefer something else?

Comment: I don't know a community preference, but if you're fine with leaving it could have value of preventing someone else from adding a similar answer.