# parsing an array of JSON objects - null value preventing upsert

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, meteor

I am parsing an array of objects, and there's about 12 fields in each.  I am doing this with two nested `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` functions,  and ran into a `null` field several responses in.

I am expecting to get an embedded object, `... "caption": {"id":"some id", "text":"some text"}`, but am instead getting a `null` in some cases.  My schema does not require the field to have a value, but the document is getting kicked out.

How can I get around this? Would expect the null just to insert a blank value, but that is not the case.  I am working within the Meteor.js framework, but the snippet I need help with below is just plain old javascript and a mongodb upsert.  The error is on the caption.text line.

```
Meteor.methods({
'getMethod': function (var1, var2) {
    check (var1, Number);
    this.unblock();
    var url = "https://www.url.com/"+var1+"/stuff?"+token+"&param="+var2;
    var result = HTTP.call("GET", url);
    if(result.statusCode===200) {
        var aArray = JSON.parse(result.content).data;
            for(var i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++){
                var id = aArray[i].id;
                var aItem = {
                   _id: aArray[i].id,
                   userId: aArray[i].user.id,
                   username: aArray[i].user.username,
                   created_time: parseInt(aArray[i].created_time),
                   type: aArray[i].type,
                   caption: aArray[i].caption.text, // THIS LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR !!
                }
                Collection.upsert(id, {$set: aItem}, {validationContext: 'upsertForm'}, function(error, result) {
                    if (error){
                        console.log("Error:", error);
                        return aArray;
                    }
                });
            }
    } else {
            console.log("Error: ", result.statusCode);
            var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
            throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary to check if there's a text property on the caption:

```
caption: (aArray[i].caption.text) ? aArray[i].caption.text : ''
```

Edit : If the caption property is questionable, then use the following:

```
caption: (aArray[i].caption) ? aArray[i].caption.text : ''
```

h/t RobG

Comment: That won't stop the error as it still attempts to access `aArray[i].caption.text`. You probably meant: `aArray[i].caption? aArray[i].caption.text : ''`

Comment: OP said he expected an embedded object: `"caption": {"id":"some id", "text":"some text"}`, so I presumed the caption property will always be there, but on further inspection you're correct as that's the only time OP is using the caption prop.

Comment: @Data @RobG fell asleep and didn't get a chance to look at this last night, but thank you fro getting back to me. the caption property is always there, and the instances that are giving me trouble are `"caption": null`

Comment: Someone on a slack channel i'm on suggested creating an underscore.js mixin for the null value, so I may look into that as it is a more portable solution.  But thank you for helping with the ternary operator option @Data

Comment: @pingo—exactly. So if `caption: null` then `caption.text` is going to throw `can't get property text of null`.

Comment: Thank you @RobG.  here is the other solution if you were interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058193/remove-empty-properties-falsy-values-from-object-with-underscore-js