# What has changed in Lodash from 3 to 4 that this code is not working?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a code like this:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const fn = _.partialRight(_.pick, _.identity);

const x = { some: 'value', empty: null };

const y = fn(x);

console.log('x:', x);
console.log('y:', y);
```

`fn` is supposed to [remove empty properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058193/remove-empty-properties-falsy-values-from-object-with-underscore-js#comment41184386_23708667)

Result with Lodash 3.10.1:

```
x: { some: 'value', empty: null }
y: { some: 'value' }
```

Result with Lodash 4.15.0:

```
x: { some: 'value', empty: null }
y: {}
```

What has changed in Lodash 4 that it's not working anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `const fn = _.partialRight(_.pick, _.identity)` to 
`const fn = _.partialRight(_.pickBy, _.identity);`

`_.pick` used to be just one function but they broke it out into `_.pick` and `_.pickBy` in the latest updates. you would use `_.pick` when you are passing in known keys and `_.pickBy` when you are using a custom function to test if a key/value should be picked based on your own parameters,

https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#pick

https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#pickBy

Answer (score 1):

Updating from 3.10.1 to 4.17.21

The functions I have needed to update so far are:

```
_contains to _.includes
_.pluck to _.map
_.findWhere to _.find
_.first to ._head
_.object to _.fromPairs
```